# Enclosing folder shortcut not working from Desktop with Desktop backup enabled

Tags: macos, mac, icloud, finder, shortcut

Usually, when I use the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> when I am on the Desktop, my Mac opens a Finder window of the parent folder where the Desktop folder is located (hence the enclosing folder).

However, since I have enabled iCloud backup of the Desktop and Documents folders, the enclosing folder shortcut from the Desktop no longer opens up the finder window where the Desktop folder is located. Instead, the shortcut does nothing.

I believe the problem is the iCloud backup option. When you turn on the Desktop backup feature, the Desktop folder is actually stored in the iCloud Drive section, rather than the User folder where it usually would be.

I still want my Desktop folder to be backed up, but I also want the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> shortcut from the Desktop to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The parent folder of the Desktop is the Home folder, or iCloud Drive, if you turn on the Desktop backup feature. The key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> is go to "Enclosing folder", so it just opens the iCloud Drive.

You can press <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to go to the Home folder from Desktop/Finder. See **Go** menu for more.

You can also open **Finder** (from menu bar) > **Settings...** > **General** > **New Finder windows show:** select your Home folder. Then you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to open the Home folder in a new Finder window.